# About the array which allocated in JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I wrote a function allocating Java array in Android JNI. However, if this function is called continuously from Java, an error[*Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)] will occur.

C++

```
static jbyteArray buffer = NULL;
static int cbuflen = 0;
jbyteArray Java_com_sample_buffer_Buffer_updateBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jlong handle, jint buflen)
{
    if(buflen > cbuflen){
        if(buffer != NULL) env->DeleteLocalRef(buffer);
        buffer = env->NewByteArray(buflen);
        cbuflen = buflen;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Java

```
byte[] buf = conv.updateBuffer(buflen);
```

Should not I use this way? Or is there some measures?

Comment: What do you mean by "called continuously"? Are you calling it from multiple threads?

Comment: Why? Why write this in JNI at all? It's more efficient in Java, and there are classes in Java that already do this for you, e.g. ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep jobject (like jbyteArray) between JNI calls you need to make it a GlobalRef:

```
jbyteArray temp_buffer = env->NewByteArray(buflen);
buffer = (jbyteArray)env->NewGlobalRef(temp_buffer);
```

Only then remeber to delete object to free memory:

```
env->DeleteGlobalRef(buffer);
```

Comment: cf. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html#local_and_global_references .  Also, if you enable CheckJNI (described later in that page), Dalvik will complain very loudly when it sees things like this.

Comment: @Mārtiņš Možeiko, in your code, is `temp_buffer` auto-released, or should `env->DeleteLocalRef(temp_buffer)` be called?

Comment: Local references are automatically released when you return from JNI method. So it is not needed. But you can explicitly manage lifetime of local references if you want. Either with DeleteLocalRef or do it in bulk with PopLocalFrame.